# How to add decimals after every 3 digit starting from right side in a list having tuple of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ip-address

I have a list having tuples. I want to put decimal point in between every 3 digit of tuple starting for right.

Input:

```
[(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]
```

output:

```
[(172.031.028.000, 171.031.011.000), (10.010.043.016, 171.031.011.111), (172.031.028.011, 172.031.031.121)]
```

Note: have to put decimal from right side only cos they are IP

I think If I can access each element one by one, seperate it with 3 digits starting from right side and then join with decimal and finally put them back in same format should do the job. This is my thinking right now but there could be a better way to do it as well.

I was trying to test it with just one number but I m not sure how to do it for every element in the list of tuples.

```
num = "123456789032"
n = 3
x = num[-3:]
y = num[-6:-3]
z = num[-9:-6]
aa = num[:-9]`enter code here`
```

Outformat :

```
[(172.031.028.000, 171.031.011.000), (10.010.043.016, 171.031.011.111), (172.031.028.011, 172.031.031.121)]
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick response. All solutions are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
data = [(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]

result = []
for i in data:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        val = str(j)[::-1]   #Reverse string
        # convert string to chunks of 3 and join
        temp.append(".".join(val[m:m+3] for m in range(0, len(str(val)), 3))[::-1])
    result.append(tuple(temp))   #Append to result. 

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('172.031.028.000', '171.031.011.000'),
 ('10.010.043.016', '171.031.011.111'),
 ('172.031.028.011', '172.031.031.121')]
```

Answer (score 1):

So iterate over each tuple, then each ip. You have the sections right for the ip so add to a temporary list which you will cast to tuple(as tuples are immutable so you can't change what you already have)

```
tup=[(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]

for j,t in enumerate(tup):
  a=[]
  for ip in t:
    s=str(ip)
    x = s[-3:]
    y = s[-6:-3]
    z = s[-9:-6]
    aa = s[:-9]
    formatted='{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(aa,z,y,x)
    a.append(formatted)
  tup[j]=tuple(a)

print(tup) # [('172.031.028.000', '171.031.011.000'), ('10.010.043.016', '171.031.011.111'), ('172.031.028.011', '172.031.031.121')]
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible version with `re` module:

```
data = [(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]

import re

from pprint import pprint
pprint([tuple(map(lambda v: re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?!$)', r'\1.', str(v)[::-1])[::-1], d)) for d in data])
```

Prints:

```
[('172.031.028.000', '171.031.011.000'),
 ('10.010.043.016', '171.031.011.111'),
 ('172.031.028.011', '172.031.031.121')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my take:

```
data = [(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]

# Add the dots to the IP
def proc_ip(a: int):
    a = str(a)
    return f'{a[:3]}.{a[3:6]}.{a[6:9]}.{a[9:]}'

# Add the dots to both ips on the tuple
def proc_tuple(a: tuple):
    return (proc_ip(a[0]), proc_ip(a[1]))

# Process each tuple
result = [proc_tuple(elem) for elem in data]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(num):
   num = str(num)
   return  '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(num[:-9], num[-9:-6], num[-6:-3], num[-3:])
```

This is an easy one liner converter based on your code. ;) `num=str(num)` is there to use slice notation - when posting list of tuples, you posted numbers as integers, while your test was on strings.

If we wrap our slices in `int()`, we can get rid of obsolete zeroes. (127.000.000.001 will become 127.0.0.1):

```
def convert(num):
   num = str(num)
   return  '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(int(num[:-9]), int(num[-9:-6]), int(num[-6:-3]), int(num[-3:]))
```

Now, as to converting your list, let's use list comprehension! That makes another one liner.

List comprehension is basically a compressed simple `for` loop.

```
input_list = [(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]

output_list = [(convert(num1), convert(num2)) for num1, num2 in input_list]
print(output_list)
```

---

Both versions working shown below:

```
>>> def convert(num):
...    num = str(num)
...    return  '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(num[:-9], num[-9:-6], num[-6:-3], num[-3:])
... 
>>> input_list = [(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]
>>> 
>>> output_list = [(convert(num1), convert(num2)) for num1, num2 in input_list]
>>> print(output_list)
[('172.031.028.000', '171.031.011.000'), ('10.010.043.016', '171.031.011.111'), ('172.031.028.011', '172.031.031.121')]
```

```
>>> def convert(num):
...    num = str(num)
...    return  '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(int(num[:-9]), int(num[-9:-6]), int(num[-6:-3]), int(num[-3:]))
... 
>>> input_list = [(172031028000, 171031011000), (10010043016, 171031011111), (172031028011, 172031031121)]
>>> 
>>> output_list = [(convert(num1), convert(num2)) for num1, num2 in input_list]
>>> print(output_list)
[('172.31.28.0', '171.31.11.0'), ('10.10.43.16', '171.31.11.111'), ('172.31.28.11', '172.31.31.121')]
>>>
```